# Why is TensorContract[x, {}] not always x?

Tags: symbolic, tensors

If I use `TensorTranspose` on an undefined symbol, nothing happens unless the permutation is the identity. For instance, `TensorTranpose[x, {1,2,3}]` gives `x`, but `TensorTranspose[x, {2, 1, 3}]` remains unevaluated. This seems like good behavior.

I would likewise expect `TensorContract` to remain unevaluated, unless the second argument is an empty list (no contractions) in which case it should do nothing. However, `TensorContract[TensorTranspose[x, {2, 1, 3}], {}]` strangely gives `TensorTranspose[x, {2, 1}]`.

Stranger still, the outcome depends on the permutation in `TensorTranspose`; in the rank-3 case, this only happens with `{2, 1, 3}`. For rank-4, the unexpected cases are:

```
{2, 1, 3, 4}    TensorTranspose[x, {2, 1}]
{3, 1, 2, 4}    TensorTranspose[x, {3, 1, 2}]
{3, 2, 1, 4}    TensorTranspose[x, {3, 2, 1}]
```

It seems like, for whatever reason, it likes chopping off tails of these permutations that coincide with the identity. Is this a bug? And what might be the underlying issue?

Comment: This is not a bug. We can see it as a canonicalization step. TensorTranspose only needs to know the slots that change, so it ignores information regarding the slots that do not change. Effectively, this is behavior inherited from the internal use of Cycles notation, which also ignores slots that do not change.

Comment: Great to know, thanks. Now that I know what I'm looking for, I see it in the documentation for `TensorTranspose`: one of the examples under Properies & Relations is `TensorTranspose[array, {2, 1}] == TensorTranspose[array, {2, 1, 3}]` which evaluates to `True`.